# Response from Web form won't display anything after a space on the console

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

I've run into another issue and was hoping someone can help me figure it out. I've managed to pull information from a form and store it in a database. But I noticed that when I display the data onto the console parts of the information are left behind when there is a space in between. For example, the value for the options element for room can be "learning web development". When I try to display that into the console it only gives me "Learning". What is weird is that all of the words including spaces in between are added into the database.

```
 <form class="form-container"  method="POST">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Room</label>
                <select name="room" class="form-select" required aria-label="select example">
                {{#each room}}
                <option class="rooms" value={{this.room}}>{{this.room}}</option>
                {{/each}}
                </select>
                <label>Session</label>
                <select name="session" class="form-select" required aria-label="select example">
                {{#each room}}
                    <option class="rooms" value={{this.session_name}}>{{this.session_name}}</option>
                {{/each}}
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Time</label>
                <input type="time" name="count_time" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Count</label>
                <input type="number" name="room_counts" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Count">
            </div>

            <div class="button-container">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>       
          
        </form>
```

Here is the node js code:

```
app.post('/count', (req,res)=>{

    console.log(req.body.session);
    console.log(req.body);
   
    res.redirect('/count');

});
```

Here is the response on the console:

```
Learning
{
  room: 'Kenmore',
  session: 'Learning',
  count_time: '13:33',
  room_counts: '100'
}
```

session: Learning. Is supposed to be session: Learning Web Development. I want to use the value from session to compare it with what's in the database. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explain

Take this line for example:

```
<option class="rooms" value={{this.session_name}}>{{this.session_name}}</option>
```

If `this.session_name` is `learning web development` then it will become:

```
<option class="rooms" value=learning web development>{{this.session_name}}</option>
```

And `value` is just 'learning', `web` and `development` will be considered as attributes of `option` tag like `class` or `value` (You can see the colors of the text)

#### Action

You should put the double quotes around the variable

```
<option class="rooms" value="{{this.session_name}}">{{this.session_name}}</option>
```

It will become:

```
<option class="rooms" value="learning web development">{{this.session_name}}</option>
```

Comment: Wow Thanks again for explaining this to me